# move fragment(?) by swiping and show underlying fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Small question, but I think it is an interresting one as I haven't found the answer yet:

what is being used in the Youtube app to be able to swipe the fragment(?) to the right and showing the options behind it. You can do it on the main page and then your personal settings are being displayed.

Anyone have an idea how this is done? I saw it in one other (none-google) app too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get similar effect in app you can use ViewPager.

Some information and code examples: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

Comment: the viewpager swipes in the view from the left, instead of having it look like that the view is behind the other, right? Or do you think they use this in the youtube app?

Comment: Oh you mean that fragment. Check this out http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/06/emerging-ui-pattern-side-navigation.html

Comment: YES! THAT IS THE ONE :D Thanks a lot! Just had no idea what that thing was called...had a quick look at the page..not able to check it further now (@work, this is hobby stuff ;)